# Some Specific URLs are not Debug at LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

While sharing the following URL on LinkedIn I found that LinkedIn is not taking title and description so thought to run debug tool so that it will correct this issue but it's not. Also, like feature is not working for this URL.
https://swertresresult.ph/

And after running debug, it is showing error

Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can. Go Back

This issue is only with this URL.. Similar URL is this (mybridaldresses.pk/bridal-mehndi-dresses-pakistani-designers-2018/) which is working perfectly.

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

While sharing on LinkedIn, you can determine which title, description and image will appear. To achieve this, your pages must contain some meta tags.

The following tags that must exist on your page.

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the page"/>
<meta property='og:image' content='http://yourdomain.com/test.jpg"/>
<meta property='og:description' content='Description of the page"/>
<meta property='og:url' content='http://www.example.com/URL of the article"/>
```

Also, there are some limitations for images. Maximum image size is allowed is 1 MB. And smaller images from 80x150px will not be accepted.